# inserting an image to excel

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

im using visualbasic express. I want to insert image to excel application. I have succeed it. here is the code;

```
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object

    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oExcel.Visible = True
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    oSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Logo\logo.bmp", False, True, 415, 1, 20, 30)
```

it works well. But instead of giving the location of the picture ("C:\Logo\logo.bmp"), i want to put the image itself. I mean i want to change the last line like this:

```
    oSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Me.Picturebox1.image , False, True, 415, 1, 20, 30)
```

But it does not work. Is there a way to insert picture to excel without using the location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm pretty sure there's no way to add the image without using a file name. According to the [MSDN docs for Shapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes.addpicture%28v=office.14%29.aspx), there does not appear to be any overload of `AddPicture` that takes anything other than a string to determine what image you want to insert.

Is the goal here to add the image that you don't necessarily have on disk somewhere (or don't know where on disc it is)? If that's the case, you can get the location (path or URI) of the image with the `ImageLocation` property and pass that to `AddPicture`. You could also first save the image to disk using `Image.Save()` and the pass the new path to `AddPicture`.