# How to insert Picture from SQL to EXCEL using VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb.net

So Is there no other way to insert a picture from SQL server to VB.NET 2010?

I know that to put it into Excel you have to declare the file path, but I wish not to use that part, I would want to call the picture from SQL and put it in my Excel file, but I'm still searching how, I would be grateful for any ideas. Thank you!

Edit: this is the code I am currenly using

```
    objWorksheet.Shapes.AddPicture("PICTURE LOCATION HERE", _
                                   Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, _
         Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 50, 50, 300, 45)
```

I would want it to be like this

```
    objWorksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(SpecChar, _
                                   Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, _
         Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 50, 50, 300, 45)
```

Where `Spechar` contains the image that I am currently using which I have retrieved in MSSQL database

Comment: The question is how to insert a picture WITHOUT saving to a file?

Comment: @IvanH My question is, Inserting a picture to a Excel spreadsheet without using a file from your computer. The image source would come from a stared procedure in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you had some code to go along with it. You can query the database, convert it to an image and then insert the image into an excel spreadsheet.

how to retrieve image:
[VB.net - insert/retrieve picture from mysql Database directly to/from a Picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033634/vb-net-insert-retrieve-picture-from-mysql-database-directly-to-from-a-pictureb)

how to insert vb.net image into excel:
[inserting an image to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387503/inserting-an-image-to-excel)

sorry, you want it directly, you can use this:
https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/

Comment: Marked this as answer because there is no way to put a picture into a MS Spreadsheet from SQL to Excel Directly, you have to save it from Database into file, then transfer the file into your Excel sheet.